# Sending multiple selected ID's from table into route using Node and Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

## Backstory:

Hi! I'm a complete noob at JavaScript and Node so I might be in over my head.

I'm connected to a DB which contains events with questions asked on that event. Users get to answer the questions and the answers get recorded to the DB.

Im using Node, Express and MySQL to fetch the data from the DB through a route. The Questions then get displayed in a table using a "forEach".

I'm also using "tabletools"(www.tabletools.net) for sorting and searching the displayed data.

## To the case:

I'm with "tabletools" trying to use "select multiple rows" to fetch the Question_ID from the selected rows. I have no idea how to accomplish this at the moment, but I'm currently trying this method:

```
$('#fbody tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );

$('#generate').click( function () {

     alert(table.rows('.selected').data());
} );
```

"#generate" is the ID of the button associated with the table.I'm currently just trying to "alert" the result to see if it works...

I want to acces the attribute "value" in the Table Row-tag. I do not want to access the text inside the Table Data-tag.

The table looks like this:

```
<table id="fbody" class="table table-striped">
               <div id="controlPanel"><h4><small>Export to: </small></h4></div>
               <button id="generate">Generate</button>
                <thead>
                   <% data2.forEach(function (event){ %>

                   <th><%= event.name %></th>
                   <th><%= event.location %></th>
                    <% }); %>
                </thead>
                <% data.forEach(function (question) { %>

                    <tr id="answer<%= question.course_module_id %>" value="<%= question.course_module_id %>">
                        <td><a href="/answers/<%= question.course_module_id %>?type=<%= question.question_type %>"><%= question.name %></a></td>
                        <td><%= question.location %></td>
                    </tr>

                    <% }); %>
            </table>
```

Sorry if it looks a bit messy...

## TL;DR:

I want to be able to access "value" inside the TR-tag of the table, since that contains the question_ID, so that I can push multiple Question_ID's to  a new route so that I can send them with the SQL Query...

Note: course_module_id is the same as the question_id which i inner join in SQL later on.

## Update:

I've now managed to console log all the ID's that are selected with this code:

```
var arr = [];
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generate").click(function(){
       $(".selected").each(function(i, obj){
           arr[i++] = $(this).data('value');
       });
       $.each(arr, function(index, val) {
           console.log(val);
       });
    });
});
```

Now the part that remains is sending these values in to a route, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Let me see if I undestand..do you want to send a list of selected (in a datatable) to function node?

Comment: Yes! I want to select rows, then send the question_id's (from tr attribute "value") to my node app!

Answer (score 0):

You can send with post method and insert a form in the table, somelike this:

**HTML:**

```
  <form id="send">
    <table id="fbody" class="table table-striped">
        <div id="controlPanel">
            <h4><small>Export to: </small></h4></div>
        <button id="generate">Generate</button>
        <thead>
            <% data2.forEach(function (event){ %>

                <th>
                    <%= event.name %>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <%= event.location %>
                </th>
                <% }); %>
        </thead>
        <% data.forEach(function (question) { %>

            <tr id="answer" value="<%= question.course_module_id %>">
                <td>
                    <a href="/answers/<%= question.course_module_id %>?type=<%= question.question_type %>">
                        <%= question.name %>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= question.location %>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <% }); %>
    </table>

    <button onclick="sendValues();">Send</button>


</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function sendValues() {
    var values = [],
        value = {};
    value.id = '';

    $('tr[id="answer"]').each(function(key, val) {
        value.id = val.value;
        values[key] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/send',
        success: function(ret) {
            if (ret == true)
                alert("Ok");
            else {
                alert("Not ok");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here, with Jquery we interate the all *tr*. For you interate the only tr selected, you can do it verifyind with Jquery too, in this case depends the methodoly of the input. And then is create the json and array with the values selecteds, before to send to node.

**Node.js**

```
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    var values = req.body;

    values.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry.id); // The id will show here
    });
    res.send(true);
});
```

Node gets the values in through post method and interate too. For your case, try do it and ask for doubts.

Comment: Thank you for that thorough response! I'm currently using "exports.get('/answers/:questionid?', function(req, res){ etc etc})"  to render my view on that specific route. I have all my routes in the same "app.js" file. is it still possible to do the way you explained?

Comment: yes, you only need to add more one route. Ex: exports.post('/send, function(req, res){ etc etc}). No problems..